# MySQL check if multiple rows exist

Tags: mysql

```
Here you can find how to check row existance:
SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM table1 WHERE some_condition);
```

How to efficiently existance of multiple rows from table like:

```
SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM table1 WHERE key = 0);
SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM table1 WHERE key = 2);
```

from table:

```
key,username
0,foo
1,bar
2,boo
```

to return positive only if both rows (with key 0 and 2) was found?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT count(distinct key) = 2  FROM table1 WHERE key in (0, 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT sum(`key` = 0) as key0_count,
       sum(`key` = 2) as key2_count 
FROM your_table
```

Comment: And how is that better from `SELECT EXISTS` and why key0_count?

Comment: It is one single query without any subqueries.

Comment: What is `key0_count` ?

Comment: `key0_count` is the number of times `key = 0` in your table. If it is `0` then it is not in your table.

Comment: @Ulta . . . If you have an index on `key`, then multiple `exists` statements are probably faster.  If you do not have an index, then this may be faster, because it only requires one full scan of the table.